# Higher order phase transition

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, experimental-physics, phase-transition

It is well a lot of realisations of first and second order phase transitions.

Is some real experemental realisations of higher order phase transition?

Comment: I think the modern classification is into the *first order phase transitions* and  the *continuous phase transitions* (order greater than 1). But your question still makes sense. My guess would be *yes*... but I cannot give any examples.

Comment: Bose-Einstein condensation can be considered as a third order phase transition, as heat capasity of the mixture has a discontinuous derivative. I can give a reference to I.A. Kvasnikov's textbook on Thermodynamics and statistical physics, namely vol. 2, Ch. 2, par. 2 Ideal non-relativistic Bose-gas. There one can find a pedagogical and detailed calculation of the heat capasity and its dependence on temperature.
But I am not sure, if there is an English translation of this textbook, so I am really sorry, if it does not work for you.